# Correlations between different Likert types and different types of variables

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, likert, continuous-data

I have two questions to ask:

1. Can I correlate an independent continuous variable and a dependent categorical variable?
2. The ratings on the Likert scale are different for both the scales, one has ranging from strongly disagree to strongly agree and the other from much more to co workers to much more to me. Can I correlate between them? The dependent variable is group cohesion and the independent variable is supervisors preferential treatment.

Comment: If both IV & DV are likert scales, in what sense is the DV categorical?